# Is there anyway to automate the process regarding JIT enabled after the VM creation in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, jit, azure-policy

Is there any policy to automate the process for the JIT enabled after the VM creation?
Currently, the issue is that many users are created the VM and have not enabled the JIT. We need to watch every time. And need to enable it at every month end.

Answer (score 0):

You can Enable JIT on your VMs using PowerShell:

To enable just-in-time VM access from PowerShell, use the official Microsoft Defender for Cloud PowerShell cmdlet `Set-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy`.

**Example** - Enable just-in-time VM access on a specific VM with the following rules:

- Close ports 22 and 3389
- Set a maximum time window of 3 hours for each so they can be opened per approved request
- Allow the user who is requesting access to control the source IP addresses
- Allow the user who is requesting access to establish a successful session upon an approved just-in-time access request

The following PowerShell commands create this JIT configuration:

1. Assign a variable that holds the just-in-time VM access rules for a VM:

   **$JitPolicy = (@{
   id="/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTIONID/resourceGroups/RESOURCEGROUP/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VMNAME";
   ports=(@{
   number=22;
   protocol="*";
   allowedSourceAddressPrefix=@("*");
   maxRequestAccessDuration="PT3H"},
   @{
   number=3389;
   protocol="*";
   allowedSourceAddressPrefix=@("*");
   maxRequestAccessDuration="PT3H"})})**
2. Insert the VM just-in-time VM access rules into an array:

   **$JitPolicyArr=@($JitPolicy)**
3. Configure the just-in-time VM access rules on the selected VM:

   **Set-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy -Kind "Basic" -Location "LOCATION" -Name "default" -ResourceGroupName "RESOURCEGROUP" -VirtualMachine $JitPolicyArr**

Use the -Name parameter to specify a VM. For example, to establish the JIT configuration for two different VMs, VM1 and VM2, use: `Set-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy -Name VM1` and `Set-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy -Name VM2`.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/just-in-time-access-usage?tabs=jit-config-powershell%2Cjit-request-asc